# Jmeter If Controller validation for integer raises exception

Tags: jmeter

I do have the following Test Plan
[image]

[image]

The "If Controller" raises the following exception :

> 018-05-30 14:32:30,822 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.String

How I can do the int validation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single equal sign is assigning a variable, you need double equal signs to check equality, see [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) examples

> use the condition: ${__jexl3(${VAR} == 23)}

And use similar approach:

```
${__jexl3(${myCounter} == 24)}
```

Comment: Same exception for :

${__jexl3(${myCounter}>0)}

Comment: @bbx402 It's working for me, make sure checkbox is checked for `Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?`

Comment: did you tried with ">" (greater than) ? or with "==" ?

Comment: @bbx402 both are working with `Interpret Condition as Variable Expression?` checked with your code (jmeter 4)